# What is the difference between aop:config vs aop:aspectj-autoproxy?

Tags: java, spring-aop

What is the difference between aop:config vs aop:aspectj-autoproxy?

Application makes use of Spring AOP framework/Custom Spring Aspects and not the full blown AspectJ aspects. Whether using aop:config will suffice in above scenario?

Comment: Do read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question with specific issue you face. In its current state question is likely to be downvoted / flagged for closure.

Comment: @Bond-JavaBond Does it look better??